# update function in php

Tags: php, mysql, function, sql-update

I have a update function that for now updates the required changes to MySQL database when I run index.php.

This is updating my password buy not the name field, ive been over the code and can not work out why.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Index that tells what id and fields to update with entered data**

```
    <?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

$userInsert = DB::getInstance()->update('users', 1, array(
    'password'   => 'newpass',
    'name'       => 'Ben'
));
```

**Function in different php that updated database**

```
    public function update($table, $id, $fields) {
    $set = '';
    $x = 1;

    foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
        $set .= "{$name} = ?";
        if($x < count($fields)) {
            $set .= ',';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} = 'newpassword' WHERE id = {$id}";

    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I believe it to be a small error or mistype but I can not see the problem.

As you can see bellow the password field has been changed but the name has not
[image]

Comment: Echo out the query after you've filled in the variables, and you'll see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Take Jessica's approach, the problem is banging you on the nose.  $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} = 'newpassword' WHERE id = {$id}";

Comment: You're never actually updating your username. SET username = 'blah',password = 'blahblah'

Comment: @InGodITrust Um.... apparently its banging you on the nose too

Comment: @InGodITrust Have you ever seen a query that looks like this work? UPDATE TABLE SET username = ? = 'newpassword'

Comment: @Rottingham Thank you, I originally used the answer but read your comment. excellent always the small errors that I can never see.

Comment: @Beep happens to each of us, all the time :-) That's the biggest problem with PHP, its such a loose language it doesn't 'care' when you flub like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function update($table, $id, $fields) {
    $set = '';
    $x = 1;

    foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
        $set .= "{$name} = \"{$value}\"";
        if($x < count($fields)) {
            $set .= ',';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: @InGodITrust It does fix the problem. whats your deal?

Comment: @InGodITrust this answer is pretty self-explanatory if you read the question: it's the OP's code, slightly modified to remove the illogic.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use of `prepare` and `execute` in **PDO**:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE '. $table .' SET username = :username, password = :password WHERE id = '. $id;
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array(
    ':username' => 'ben',
    ':password' => 'newpassword'
));
```

Comment: This works but it doesn't fix his problem but showing him what was wrong

Comment: This is a good practice in general, but if you look at his code, he is trying to make a "universal" update function that will allow for any number of fields and can be applied on any table.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private function update($table, $primaryKey, $fields) {
        $query = 'UPDATE `' . $this->table . '` SET ';
        
        foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
            $query .= '`' . $key . '` = :' . $key . ',';
        }

        $query = rtrim($query, ',');

        $query .= ' WHERE `' . $this->primaryKey . '` = :primaryKey';

        $fields['primaryKey'] = $fields['id'];
    
        $this->query($query, $fields);

    }
```

> An example of an update function. Attention mine is inside a class and the query is another function and passes as an object.